How can I change the initial directory of apps back to the home directory?
Apps like the XFCE4 terminal and Thunar used to open in the home directory. However, recently they started to open in $HOME/.config/xfce4/panel. I want to change this back to the home directory. How can I do that?

Does this persist after a logout or reboot?

@grawity_u1686 I can test after about 10 minutes. (downloading a file)

Check how these are launched. If you have "current dir" set to $HOME/ just before launching, you might probably see what you wish.

Rebooting the computer fixed it. However, for some reason I cannot post an answer. (I just tried and nothing got posted)
